# Function converging in both $L^1$ and $L^2$ norm

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose a function $f$ is in both $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. For $m=1,2,\ldots$, let $$f_m(x) = f(x)\cdot \chi_{[-m,m]}(x)\cdot \chi_{\{ \lvert f(y)\rvert \leqslant m\}}(x)$$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic function. Then why is $f_m(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ in both $L^1$ and $L^2$?

This was used in an answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560316/two-definitions-of-fourier-transform-for-l1-and-l2-coincide), but I don't understand the explanation there. Perhaps someone can explain it in simpler terms, or show the proof?

Comment: Use dominated convergence.  $f_m \to f$ pointwise, and $|f_n - f|$ is dominated by $2|f|$, while $|f_n - f|^2$ is dominated by $(2|f|)^2$.  By assumption both dominating functions are integrable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nate Eldredge noted, since $|f_m|\rightarrow |f|$ pointwise, and $|f_m|$ is dominated by the integrable function $|f|$, and $|f_m|^2$ is dominated by the integrable function $|f|^2$, so the conclusion follows by the dominated convergence theorem.